# Send data using msxml2.xmlhttp.3.0 to web to select Datepicker in EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker, httprequest, xmlhttprequest

The following is the HTML of part of a web page.

```
"input name="ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ContentMain$ucMktStatCtl$txtDate" type="text"
id="ctl00_ctl00_AllContent_ContentMain_ucMktStatCtl_txtDate" 
onkeypress="javascript:return fnTrapKD(event, document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_AllContent_ContentMain_ucMktStatCtl_butReport'))"
value="02/24/2006" class="hasDatepicker">
```

I tried to use the following code to access the data.

```
Dim strPostData As String: strPostData  = "ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ContentMain$ucMktStatCtl$txtDate=02/24/2006"
 Dim xmlhttp: Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.3.0")
  xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://www.cboe.com/data/mktstat2.aspx#VIX", False
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  xmlhttp.send (strPostData)
```

I am getting `responsetext` with 404 - File or directory not found. But the site does accept the input in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

The mozilla firefox addon firebug helps to analyse the http request.
Post tab shows the parameters which are sent.
The URL should be http://www.cboe.com/data/mktstat2.aspx

[image]

```
Sub test()

    Dim strPostData As String
    strPostData = "ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ContentMain$ucMktStatCtl$butReport=Get Report&ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ContentMain$ucMktStatCtl$ddlNav=&ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ContentMain$ucMktStatCtl$txtDate=05/31/2013&ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ucHeader$CBOEHeaderSearchBox$txtHeaderSearch=Search&ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ucHeader$ucCBOEHeaderQuoteBox$txtHeaderQuote=Quote"

    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")

    xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://www.cboe.com/data/mktstat2.aspx", False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.send (strPostData)

    MsgBox xmlhttp.responseText
End Sub
```